# Typescript Generics: type safe generics for parameters of a method of an object

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to use generics to invoke a function of an object with its respective parameters from a single wrapper function.

Here is what I am trying to achieve:

```
class Class1 {
  method() {}
}

class Class2 {
  method(x: string) {}
}

class Class 3 {
  method(x: number, y: string) {}
}

// valid
wrapper(new Class1());
// valid
wrapper(new Class2(), 'hello');
// valid
wrapper(new Class3(), 10, 'hello');
// invalid
wrapper(new Class3(), '10', 'hello');
```

Here is my attempt:

```
function wrapper<
  M extends { method: F },
  F extends (..._: any[]) => any,
  P extends Parameters<F>
>(m: M, ...p: P) {
  m.method(...p);
}
```

This works, but does not provide type safety on the parameter `p`. I am able to pass parameters that are not valid for the function `m.method`.

Comment: You only need 1 generic type parameter: https://tsplay.dev/mA888N

Comment: Your function has no inference site for `F` (constraints are not used for inference) and thus nothing will join `M` and `P` the way you want.   Too many generic type parameters will make things looser than you want.  You can make your function generic only in `P` as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/mbvvEm) and it should work. Does that fully address your question? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: You both answered at the same time and both of your answers are useful and working @pink @jcalz! If you write an answer I will +1 both of you, but I will select jcalz since he was a bit more detailed with his answer.

Comment: @pink beat me by a few seconds so I'll defer to them unless they don't want to write an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the compiler doesn't have anywhere to infer `F` from (other type parameters are not used as inference sites), it defaults to its constraint of `(...args: any[]) => any`. You really only need 1 generic type parameter here:

```
function wrapper<
  F extends (...args: any[]) => any,
>(m: { method: F }, ...p: Parameters<F>) {
//     ^^^^^^^^^ inference point for F
  m.method(...p);
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDC5QIzQN4FgBQ1oFsCmALgBYD2AJgBQCUqAvpvRpqJDPKwEyqbb7HkUAHgC5oEAgCcAlgDsA5jRSNGzBGzUBmbllyFSlEdBkBXHACM8EgDTQAnqPHT5i5ZkwB6d9ABuYEFLJMAHcJMAAHMMsKGTwguDVEaioAbg8vX39AjBDwyIlo2PjOahsAciI8EBASUpS0nz8A4NCIqJi49igNEuhEAAYyiqqauoxPaFkMpuyWvIKOzR7S-tLByura1KYMADNjGWACKRIZaBzWiQAeHmgAMWg8QQI8GTIYCgA6L7AJOQhRMAyWwAbQAujQALwAPmggNsVkwUIoOFEKF0-DIonutBsXw+YVEAAUfmA+JYIJdblDFDccB8+PpPl8wqNGEA)